*camping it up for all he was worth*/game not reckless

There was also the equally sudden appearance of piercings, tattoos and
– most shocking of all for hardcore metal fans – make-up. It was one
thing seeing Kirk Hammett – always the most (comparatively) effeminate
of the group – posing in mascara, showing off his new body tattoos and
face piercings, including a labret (a small, silver spike) dangling
below his lower lip, 1.camping it up for all he was worth in order
to alter the public perception of who the people in Metallica really
were. Seeing Lars imitating him, though stopping short of the
extravagant tattoos (Lars was game, not reckless), was also
strangely digestible, knowing what lengths Lars would go to in order
to keep Metallica in the public eye.

1 Does it mean that Kirk was pretending to be gay? Earlier in the book it says that he was kissing Lars.
2. What does the expression mean in other words?

I'm pretty sure, like your past questions, that this contains a block quote from some book. When we start reading, we think the first few words are yours. To change that, please start the quote by typing > and it will format it as a quote. (Also, could you tell us the book?)

"Pretending to be gay"—style and appearance in rock circle has always been a complicated history. It might be too much to say that Kirk was making any overt statement, simply that he was adopting styles associated with the Camp movement.

In the sense of overdone performance, all of the British Hammer films are definitely camp.

I think in most contexts, camping it up and hamming it up are more or less synonymous - they don't particularly imply that the subject is either homosexual or thespian, just (usually, deliberately, facetiously) acting in a flamboyantly exaggerated way.

@FumbleFingers - is it related to 'chewing up the scenery'?

@MichaelHarvey: I didn't even know that expression until 10 minutes ago (10 minutes because I followed the first google link to tv tropes, and was lucky to get out of that siren-like morass so quickly! :) But only a couple of days ago I was listening to a fascinating interview with Kevin Spacey. He waxed lyrical over the specific point that the best acting is not acting at all. That one I'll keep in mind, but probably not the metaphoric expression for overacting.

@FumbleFingers - I have wasted so many hours on TV Tropes! I see from that page that Hitler only metaphorically 'chewed the carpet'. As a kid I thought he did it for real when he had some kind of fit.

What the hell is the "1." in the text, and what the hell sentence does "question 2" below relate to?

@MichaelHarvey - I would say no not really. If you're chewing up the scenery it's just "extreme"; like the NOOOOOOOOOOOOO moment you know? The phrase can be used as a positive too, you know, the huge high note at the end of the number, she's chewing up the scenery.  Hamming it up is only ever negative / silly. Note too that being a "ham" is commonly used in real life (say when someone is "playing up the moment" to "get more attention" .. "look at him over there hamming it up for the news cameras, his 5 minutes of fame!") .. "chewing up the scenery" is really only used on a stage/set.

( @FumbleFingers , ironically I find Kevin Spacey to be an incredibly hammy actor! )

Camping things up can mean to act in a stereotypically 'gay' fashion (mincing, lisping, behaving effeminately, calling everyone 'ducky'), but in the context of performance it can also mean merely to act with exaggerated speech or gestures.

Camp is an aesthetic style and sensibility that regards something as
appealing because of its bad taste and ironic value.

Camp (style) - Wikipedia

English learners, much as the word "gay" can mean either

homosexual

cheerful


The word "camp" can mean either

regarding a homosexual person: behaving in a flamboyant manner

regarding acting or performing: acting in an over-the-top, corny manner.


Your partial question, "was he pretending to be gay". No, this was answered perfectly in a comment:
"...don't particularly imply that the subject is either homosexual ... just ... acting in a flamboyantly exaggerated way"
